# Surjective functions and cal'

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

$f,g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

Both are also surjective functions.

My question is if $f+g$ will be also surjective. I need to dis/prove it if it's true or false.

Now, my friend told me it's false because if you took $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ the answer will be $0$. But, $0$ is included as real number, no? So his answer is not correct.

So what is the answer?

I'd like to get some help over here.

Thanks!!

Comment: $f$ surjective means $f\left(\Bbb R\right)=\Bbb R$. That's true for $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto -x$ but not $x\mapsto 0$ because $\left(x\mapsto 0\right)\left(\Bbb R\right)=\{0\}\not= \Bbb R$. In other words, your friend is right.

Comment: To solve any mathematical question, you need to understand what the question asks. Judging by this question, I really don't think you know and understand the definition of surjective. Read the definition (in whatever source you choose), and try to see if you can discern if some basic examples of functions you know are surjections or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right. Surjective means $f(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R$, or for any $y\in \Bbb R$ there exists $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = y$. Now, if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$, they are both surjective (why?). But $h(x) = f(x) + g(x) = 0$ is not surjective, since $h(\Bbb R) = \{0\}$, for example there does not exist $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $h(x) = 1$ since $h(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.